# PHP / Mysql , compare the values from two while loops

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Is there any way to take the contents of my while query below and use it elsewhere in my php script ?. What I am trying to do is collect the answers from a quiz and then compare them to the correct answers, the problem I am having is that the answers come from one table and the questions from another, so I am currently having to run two different while queries, but I cant use $quiz in the 2nd query as it just stays fixed with the last value it spat out. What im basically trying to do it load table A, look inside for the `questionID`, select that table and pull out the correct answer. Then load table B, looking inside that, select the answer with the same `questionID` and then use an if statement to compare to to, so that if `correctanswer` = `actualanswer` = correct , and loop over this for each question. The main problem that im coming up against though is the first while pulls out all the correct answers just fine, but I cant then use that in the other while to compare too. Im not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, or if there is a better way ?.

LOOK FOR THE CORRECT ANSWER :

```
      $result0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions  
                WHERE quizID='$quizID' ORDER BY cf_id ASC");
      while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0))
       {
         $answer = $row0['correctanswer'];
       }
```

LOOK FOR THE ACTUAL ANSWER SUBMITTED :

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz 
            WHERE quizID='$quizID' AND userID='$userID' ORDER BY cf_id ASC");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { 
        $quiz = $row['quizselectanswer']; 
     }
```

Comment: Can't you do this with a join in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join is propably the best way to do this. But you could also use the php `in_array()`-Function:

```
$result0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions     WHERE quizID='$quizID' ORDER BY cf_id ASC");
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0))
{
    $answers[] = $row0['correctanswer'];
}
```

And Then

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz WHERE     quizID='$quizID' AND userID='$userID' ORDER BY cf_id ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    if(in_array($row['quizselectanswer'],$answers)){
        ...correct...

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error at the IF line in Dreamweaver with the second one ?

Comment: I forgot a bracket ). Edited on top.

Comment: Argh I spoke to soon, it appears only to be outputting one record and thats it, even if I get two questions correct it just only outputs correct once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz a, itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions
q WHERE a.quizID='$quizID' AND a.userID='$userID' and q.quizID=a.quizID and
a.quizselectanswer = q.correctanswer
```

Should return all the correct answers. If you also want the wrong answers, you need to do a outer join on the two tables.